# Not able to add node in cluster and getting exception while adding the node in Windows failover clustering

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, failover, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Recently one of the cluster node got rebooted(due to some disk corruption) for which we first removed from cluster and after that when we are trying to add it back into cluster we are facing exception.

We tried to look for different like comparing the different components on both servers but non worked(we can't run clear command for primary node as this is 2 node cluster and one node is already down)

The error stack is mentioned below:-

> Exception occurred in background operation - System.ApplicationException: An error occurred while adding nodes to the cluster 'Cluster_name'. ---> System.ApplicationException: An error occurred while adding node 'node_name' to cluster 'Cluster_name'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.ClusApiExceptionFactory.CreateAndThrow(Cluster cluster, Int32 sc, String format, Object arg0, Object arg1) at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Cluster.AddNode(String nodeName, ClusterActionCallback callback) at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.AddNodeManagement.AddNodes(ActionArgs actionArgs, ActionUpdateHelper updateHelper) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.AddNodeManagement.AddNodes(ActionArgs actionArgs, ActionUpdateHelper updateHelper) at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.AddNodeManagement.PerformAddNodes(ActionArgs actionArgs) at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ConfigurationBase.PerformActionWrapper(BackgroundOperationStatus backgroundOperationStatus, BackgroundOperationArgs parameter) at MS.Internal.ServerClusters.BackgroundOperation`2.BackgroundOperationProc(Object state)

Comment: Run: Test-Cluster -Node "failed node"

Comment: @batistuta09 the validation test already run. Let me know if any specific section's data you required.

Comment: Have you get any errors in validation wizard for this node? Try to remove cluster role from failed node and install it again.

Comment: @batistuta09 there are no errors but warnings. The server is not in cluster anymore. I had run the clear command for problematic node but it also not helping.